# Strange issue when trying to set a BooleanField value in a django model

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I'm trying to change the value of a BooleanField in one of my models, but Django won't let me. Here's the relevant code:

```
query = MyModel.objects.filter(name='example').filter(boolField=False)
print query[0].boolField
query[0].boolField = True
query[0].save()
print query[0].boolField
```

This surprisingly prints:

```
False
False
```

Any idea why the `= True` isn't sticking? Thanks in advance!

Edit: This fixed it:

```
query = MyModel.objects.get(name='example', boolField=False)
query.boolField = True
query.save()
```

It seems you can't change fields in a query that you filtered by?

Comment: Any reason why you want to do it this way? If you are fetching one object, why not use `MyModel.objects.get` ?

Comment: I changed it to `.get` and that seems to have fixed it.. Any idea why? Is it not possible to change fields that you filtered by?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's not the filtering that's the problem, it's the slicing. Each time you slice a queryset, Django gives you a **different** object:

```
f = MyModel.objects.all()[0]
f.id       # 1
id(f)      # 4326035152
ff = MyModel.objects.all()[0]
ff.id      # 1
id(ff)     # 4326035344
```

Here `f` and `ff` refer to the same underlying database row, but different actual object instances. So in your example, the instance you set the boolean on is not the same as the instance you tried to save.